# php curl post a large json object

Tags: php, json, curl

So, I have a php script which sends a large JSON object and this is the code I am using to do so.

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Now when the data is small, the request goes through smoothly. However, when the json object becomes huge it suddenly fails to send the data and instead is shows "Content-Length: 0" in the request header as if it did not include the object.

I am assuming there is a limit to how large the data could be. Is there a way to bypass that?

I have searched for similar issues and I found a solution for sending files. But the object i have here is a result set from the database and therefore I would prefer to keep the file approach as a last resort.

Thanks.

Comment: The server may have a limit to, how much large data you can send. And maybe you are crossing that limit.

Comment: I have increased all limits in php.ini and that includes "memory_limit", "post_max_size" , "max_input_time" and "max_execution_time". Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I was not talking about the limits on your side, but the server's side you are sending to.

Comment: I also have full control over the other end, and I have also increased these numbers. The reason that led me to believe it is an issue within the request is because the "Content-length" suddenly becomes 0.

Comment: Try sending the "Content-Lengh" header explicitly in your HTTP headers, which will be equal to `strlen(json_encode($data))` in your case

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have the HTTPHEADER already but you're missing the Content-length one try it like so:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-length:' . strlen($data)));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: This assumes $data is already json encoded, which it isn't. I think you may need to show a full example with his entire snippet for clarity.

Comment: oh yeah you're right! Thanks for the suggestion! @Sleavely